# Cannot install SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server

Running Windows 8.1 Pro x64 (upgraded from 8.0) with all updates installed. I'm trying to install SQL Server Management Studio 2012 using `SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe`. When the setup is initializing, I get this error:

```
ScenarioEngine.exe - Configuration parser error
-----------------------------------------------
Error parsing C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config
Parser returned error 0xC00CE556
```

I tried replacing `machine.config` with `machine.config.default` but with no success. Google has no more information regarding this, as far as I can see.

**Has anybody seen this error before? How do you solve it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `machine.config` with `machine.config.default` for **both** the 32-bit and 64-bit versions did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by installing dotnet framework 4.0 on your system.